# Which question received 10 upvotes with the lowest number of views?

Tags: discussion, up-votes

It seems to me that receiving say $10$ upvotes ("Nice Question" badge) with $50$ views is more impressive, in terms of indicating a high quality question, than receiving $10$ upvotes with $500$ views. So I would like to ask:

> **Which MSE question received $10$ upvotes with the lowest number of views?**

(Ignore subsequent upvotes and views.)

Also, since upvotes may have been easier to obtain in the "old days", I would also like to ask:

> **Among MSE questions asked after the start of $2020$, which one received $10$ upvotes with the lowest number of views?**

I've tried the "[How do I search?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/searching)" page.

If such searches are not possible, then answers to similar questions would be welcome, e.g. "Which MSE question had the highest ratio of upvotes to views at any point in time, restricted to questions with at least say $10$ upvotes?"

Comment: [SEDE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/data-explorer/info) contains various data about questions, including ViewCount. So you could write an SQL query computing Score per ViewCount and similar things. But this is only the *current* ViewCount - number of views the question had in the past isn't stored in the database.